# ¿Cómo obtener Activity en Adaptador de RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Buenas tardes, estoy personalizando un RecyclerView con CardView y también estoy usando la API de Youtube; la idea es que al hacer clic a una imagen de "Reproducir" que tengo implementado en el CardView se reproduzca el video que tiene.. como si fuera un alertdialog.

Estoy usando "YouTubeStandalonePlayer" y me pide como primer parámetro la "Activity".

Este es mi Adaptador del RecyclerView.

```
public class AdaptadorTestimonios extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorTestimonios.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
ArrayList<TestimonioBean> testi;
//API_KEY
private static String API_KEY = "myApikey";

public AdaptadorTestimonios(Context c, ArrayList<TestimonioBean> testimonioBean){
    this.context = c;
    this.testi = testimonioBean;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_testimonios,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int i = position;
    holder.cliente.setText(testi.get(i).getCliente());
    Log.i("LinkTest", testi.get(i).getLink());
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+testi.get(i).getLink()+"/mqdefault.jpg").into(holder.img);


holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     //Acá me aparece error al querer obtener la activity..
     //Me pide como primer parámetro la activity...
        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent( , API_KEY, testi.get(i).getLink(), 0, false, true);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return testi.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView card;
    TextView cliente;
    ImageView img;
    ImageButton play;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardViewTestimonio);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgTest);
        cliente = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtClienteTestimonio);
        play = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayVideo);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        cliente.setTypeface(typeface);

      }
   }
 }
```

**Entonces especificamente mi consulta sería: ¿Cómo obtengo la activity en el adaptador del RecyclerView?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es más sencillo que todo eso. En el constructor de tu adapter pasa la actividad desde el cual lo creas, algo así:

```
private Activity act;

public AdaptadorTestimonios(Activity c, ArrayList<TestimonioBean> testimonioBean){
    this.act= c;
    ...
}
```

Luego ya desde el activity donde lo creas tan solo tienes que pasarle una referencia de si misma:

```
AdaptadorTestimonios adapter = new AdaptadorTestimonios(this, ...)
```

Espero que sea esto lo que buscabas y necesitas.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor de tu adapter pasas un contexto y lo guardas como campo `context`. Dependiente que pasas al constructor de tu adapter, de este contexto puedes recibir o usarlo como la actividad que tienes que poner como primer parámetro.

`Activity` y `Application` ambos son subclases de `Context`. Si tu construyes el adapter en tu `Activity` puedes pasar `this` como contexto. Aun que lo guardas como contexto en tu adapter, sigue siendo una referencia a la actividad, y en este caso puedes arrancar tu actividad así:

```
 Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) context , API_KEY, testi.get(i).getLink(), 0, false, true);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ya intenté eso de pasarle como parámetro el contexto.. pero me obliga a parsearlo con (Activity) context; y al arrancar la app en el emulador se cierra la app y me aparece como error: `"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"`

Comment: Entonces supongo que en tu método `onCreate` de tu `Activity` pasas el `Context` al constructor del adapter. Te actualiza la respuesta para eso.

Answer (score 0):

**La forma de obtener el contexto en este caso la activity dentro de un Adapter es enviarlo al constructor**, de hecho tu constuctor esta recibiendo un contexto :

```
public AdaptadorTestimonios(Context c, ArrayList<TestimonioBean> testimonioBean){
    this.context = c;
    this.testi = testimonioBean;

}
```

puedes inicializar el Adapter con la Activity por ejemplo desde el Activity :

```
AdaptadorTestimonios mAdapter = new AdaptadorTestimonios(this, mArraytestimonioBean);
```